# Hide the cursor and make it stop moving using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, browser, cursor

I'm making a 3D game where the camera needs to be pretty much identical to the World of Warcraft one. That means, that once the screen is clicked, the cursor disappears, and when the mouse is moved, the camera rotates around a focus point (the player).

I made most of the code, the cursor does disappear when the screen is clicked, but the problem is that it is still moving, even though it isn't shown. That feels unnatural, and I'd like to have the cursor to stay at the same spot for the whole time.

So, how do I achieve this with Javascript?

The only support reqs are the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: similar question here: [link](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9105/how-to-implement-mouselook-in-the-browser)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't manipulate the position of the cursor like that in JavaScript because of the security implications that it incurs.

Comment: As I said, I know how to hide the cursor. `document.body.style.cursor = "none"` does the trick.

Comment: @Bane Ah, then the answer to your position question is that you can't manipulate the cursor position because of browser security restrictions :)

Comment: @Bane Yeah I agree, but imagine what those spam sites would do with control of your cursor? Not good :)

Comment: @TrevorSenior good question! I just did a bit of googling, but only found how to change the cursor image, **not** the position. Probably another security restriction maybe?

Answer (score 3):

*If I am getting your question right*,

Not possible via javascript, you will need flash.

But yes, some progess is really going on,

[Pointer lock api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/API/Pointer_Lock_API)

**Update:** (I had free time, so I played with it)

You can try something like this, **its not perfect,not recommended and it fails** when original mouse reaches the screen borders (however you can restrict the mouse movements in a wrapper, that will solve the problem).

**Html:**

```
<body style='width:100%;min-height:800px;overflow:hidden'>  
<img id='fakeCursor' src='http://i50.tinypic.com/359d3km.jpg'  style='z-index:1000;position:absolute;display:none' />  
<div href='javascript:void(0);' style='position:absolute;left:50px;top:10px;width:100px;height:100px;background:gray;' onclick='console.log("fake click 1");return false;'>Fake click 1</div>
<div href='javascript:void(0);' style='position:absolute;left:50px;top:130px;width:100px;height:100px;background:gray;' onclick='console.log("fake click 2");return false;'>Fake click 2</div>
</body>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var clientX,clientY;   
var fakeCursor = document.getElementById('fakeCursor'); 

var isFakeMouse = false;
document.onclick = function(e){
    if(isFakeMouse){    
        if(document.elementFromPoint(fakeCursor.style.left,fakeCursor.style.top)!=null){
            document.elementFromPoint(fakeCursor.style.left,fakeCursor.style.top).click();
            return false;
        }
        fakeCursor.style.display = 'inline';
        fakeLeft = clientX;
        fakeTop = clientY;
        var mouseLastLeft = -1;
        var mouseLastTop = -1;
        document.onmousemove = function(e){  
            if(mouseLastLeft ===-1 && mouseLastTop ===-1){
                mouseLastLeft = e.clientX;
                mouseLastTop = e.clientY;
                return;
            } 
            fakeCursor.style.left = (parseInt(fakeCursor.style.left) + ((mouseLastLeft - e.clientX)*-1)) + 'px';
            fakeCursor.style.top = (parseInt(fakeCursor.style.top) + ((mouseLastTop - e.clientY)*-1)) + 'px'; 
            mouseLastLeft = e.clientX;
            mouseLastTop = e.clientY;
        }
    }
    else{
        isFakeMouse = true;
        document.body.style.cursor = "none";
        fakeCursor.style.display = 'none';
        fakeCursor.style.left = clientX = e.clientX;
        fakeCursor.style.top = clientY = e.clientY;
        document.onmousemove = null;
    }
}
```

Here, at first click on `document`, the `real mouse` hides. When user clicks `document` again, `real mouse` would be still hidden and a new `fake mouse` (an image) will take its place. Position of the `fake mouse` would be the same where user has left the `real mouse`. `fake mouse` works (tries) to work like `real mouse`.

*Sorry for inline css and javascrict*

Comment: >Flash\n

Lost it right there. Nope, Flash is going to die, I'm not planning to use it. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @Bane, I've edited my answer and added some code. You can try my code :) Its not recommended but you should atleast see it. May be it will give you a direction to find another way